# SQL Script to loop through all records with specific condition

Tags: sql, database, select

I am trying to create an SQL script to generate number of travellers to a country based on these conditions:

- Country
- Nature of travel
- Year
- Length of Stay

  - More than 1 month
  - Less than 1 week
  - More than 1 week but less than 1 month

The final goal is to get something like this (for 1 year / 1 country):

[image]

I have tried to do the manual way (**takes me a long time**) of generate single SQL statements but I am unsure how to do it via a **PL/SQL loop**. Appreciate if anyone can show me how.

Below is the table structure in my database with the relevant fields.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what i have currently, but i am unsure about getting the number of travellers:

```
select c.country_name as country,
   a.nature_of_travel,
   case d.rn 
     when 1 then 'More than 1 month' 
     when 2 then 'Less than 1 week' 
     else 'Between 1 week and 1 month'
   end length_of_stay,
   count(*) number_of_trips, -- Supposed to use sum(number_of_travellers) here
   to_char(b.from_date,'YYYY') year   
from TB_TRAVELITINERARY b 
join TB_TRIP a on a.trip_id=b.trip_id   
join TB_COUNTRY c on b.country_code= c.country_code 
join (select rownum rn from dual connect by level < 4) d on 
  case when add_months(b.from_date,1) < b.to_date then 1
       when b.from_date+7 > b.to_date then 2
       else 3
  end = d.rn
 group by c.country_name,
    a.nature_of_travel,
    case d.rn 
      when 1 then 'More than 1 month' 
      when 2 then 'Less than 1 week' 
      else 'Between 1 week and 1 month'
    end,
    to_char(b.from_date,'YYYY')
```

I tried using sum(number_of_travellers) but it didnt work.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try this : `sum(a.number_of_travellers) as number_of_trips` and group by  `a.trip_id` and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create some views to help break things down and avoid repeated code e.g.:

```
VW_ITINERARY_DURATION { ITINERARY_ID, DURATION_IN_DAYS, DURATION_IN_MONTHS }
```

...whose durations are used to create:

```
VW_ITINERARY_NARRATIVE { ITINERARY_ID, DURATION_NARRATIVE, SORT_ORDER };
```

Then it is a simple case of `natural join`ing the tables `TB_TRAVELITINERARY`, `TB_TRIP`, `TB_COUNTRY` and `VW_ITINERARY_NARRATIVE`. If you then attempt the summation in this simple query then things may become clearer.